# Select where a value present

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database, select

First a database example:

```
id, product_id, cat, name, value
--------------------------------
1,1,Algemeen,Processor,2 Ghz
2,1,Algemeen,Geheugen,4 GB

3,2,Algemeen,Processor,3 Ghz
4,2,Algemeen,Geheugen,4 GB

5,3,Beeldscherm,Inch,22"
6,3,Beeldscherm,Kleur,Zwart
7,3,Algemeen,Geheugen,3 GB
8,3,Algemeen,Processor,3 Ghz
```

I want with one query to select the follow id's: 1,2,3,4,7,8

Because the cat = algemeen and the name = processor by these products. ID 5,6 are only present by product 3.

So, the entry's (cat and name) which are present by all products (product_id) have to be selected.

The database contains 80.000 entry's with a lot of diffrent cat's, name's and value's.

Is this possible with one query or is some php necessary? How do I do this?

My apologies for the bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
$query = mysql_query(" 
select distinct p.cat, p.name, p.value  
from producten_specs p  
inner join (  
select cat, `name`, count(*) as cnt  
from producten_specs  
where product_id in (".mysql_real_escape_string($product_ids).")  
group by cat, `name`  
having cnt = ".mysql_real_escape_string($product_ids_aantal)."  
) c on p.cat = c.cat and p.`name` = c.`name`  
where p.product_id in (".mysql_real_escape_string($product_ids).")  
ORDER BY cat,name,ABS(value) ASC 
"); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean, show ALL records where the combination of (cat, name) is present in ALL product_ids, right?

```
select t.id, t.product_id, t.cat, t.name, t.value
from (
  select cat, name
  from tbl
  group by cat, name
  having count(product_id) = count(distinct product_id)
) p
join tbl t on t.cat = p.cat and t.name = p.name
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to explain. When I see the results of the query I know if it's what I mean.

I forgot to post the query I'm using to show all items:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cat, name, value
    FROM producten_specs 
    WHERE product_id IN (1,2,3) 
    ORDER BY cat,name,ABS(value) ASC
```

It is possible to combine this query with yours.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description of the problem, you want a SQL Query that will get the records where the value of `cat` is 'Algemeen' or the value of `product_id` is 'Processor'. If this is the case, I would use this query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM producten_specs AS p
  WHERE p.cat = "Algemeen" OR p.product_id = "Processor"
  ORDER BY p.id
```

I did notice that this question is over a year old. If you found the answer you want on this site you should accept it, if not mark the question closed.